# convert from foreach to for loop

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor-2

below code working perfectly . but i need to convert it from `foreach` to `for` loop .please help me  to iteration by for loop. because i have to introduce some `if` `else` statement in entire code

```
@foreach (var item in ViewData["productSl_1"] as IEnumerable<Nazmulkp.Models.Product>)
{      
    <div class="col-md-3 ">
      <div class="thumbnail">
          <a href="#" class=""><img src="@Url.Content(item.ImagePath)" alt="Image" style="max-width:100%;"></a>
          <div class="caption">  
             <h5>@item.ProductName</h5>
             <h4>Tk.@item.Price</h4>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

Example:

I have to make sure if index number 2 than execute `<div class="col-md-3>"`

Thank you

Comment: Why does it need to be a `for` loop. And if you do want to use one, the model should be `IList<T>`

Comment: you can do `if -else` inside a `foreach` as well. Did you try it ?

Comment: @Shyju I have to make sure if index number 2 than execute  <div class="col-md-3 ">

Comment: @NazmulHasan Are you trying to apply css classes based on index ?

Comment: @KrishnaDhungana no,why i try to use css classes based on index

Comment: @NazmulHasan I posted an answer to do that.. Take a look.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You do not need to convert your `foreach` to a for loop for adding a conditional css class. Simply add a counter variable to your code and use that for your if condition as needed.

For example, the below code will add the css class `"col-md3"` to the 3rd item in your collection.

```
@{ var counter = 0;}
@foreach (var item in YouCollectionHere)
{
    <div class="@(counter==2?"col-md-3":"")">
        <h2>@item.Name</h2>
    </div>
    counter++;
}
```